# Pikaday as multi date picker

Tags: pikaday

I am using Pikaday for displaying calendar,i need multiple date selections from datepicker in one of my modules.Is pikaday calendar provides this functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You can either attach a pickaday object to each element (easiest) or create one object and shuffle it around, set the date yourself etc (harder, and there's no real point....)

Comment: I think what @magicboy meant is if it is possible to select multiple dates, not use multiple date pickers.

Comment: Well I don't think magicboy is ever going to come back and confirm :).  But for anyone else, the answer is in the examples: http://nathancahill.github.io/Pikaday/examples/date-range.html - i.e. no, you need two date pickers.

Comment: Yeah :) I hacked a little around in Pikaday and got what I needed. https://www.dropbox.com/s/rdrqpejidn7qq19/Screen%20Shot%202016-04-20%20at%2018.30.07.png?dl=0

Comment: Nice: should post the code up for others? Looks like it returns multiple dates , comma separated, or as an array? Pretty sure others may find the hack useful.

Comment: Yeah, gotta do some cleaning-upping first :). The dates are returned as an array, analogous to the date object that's being returned in the single date case.